# If else 'Not a statement' error

Tags: netbeans

For java class in school (10th grade) i need to make a restaurant choosing system that includes 12 different code blocks.

```
 if(mealChoice == true){
                        System.out.println("You have chosen to eat a crunchy taco!");}

                    else(mealChoice == false);{
                System.out.println("you have chosen to eat a cheesy double beef burrito");
                        System.out.println("I hope you enjoy it!");}
```

this is what i have and the error comes after the 'else' line and i cant fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
else(mealChoice == false);{
                         ^---
```

the `;` TERMINATES the statement, meaning you have an `else` with no "body".

Comment: when i delete the semi colon and mouse over the lightbulb it still gives me the "not a statement" message and then it also says "; expected"